# Is it safe to delete an array pointer in C++ after reassignment?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, delete-operator

Suppose I'd like to swap two array pointers in C++ which I have allocated with `new []` and different length. Is it safe to `delete []` them after swapping? What if they have the same length?

```
int *a;
int *b;
int *tmp;

a = new int[5];
b = new int[10];
tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;

delete [] a;
delete [] b;
```

Comment: Yes it's safe. As long as delete[] gets the same pointer values as were returned by new[] then it's OK.

Comment: @john So how does the compiler keep track of how much memory can be freed for each pointer?

Comment: Don't use raw pointers, C-style arrays, `new` or `delete`. `std::vector` is your friend.

Comment: @elzell The *compiler* doesn't keep track.  The same way that `free` knows how much memory to free with `malloc` in C, some extra book-keeping information is stored with the allocated memory.  It's safe in that the memory will be properly freed, but I am obligated to say that you almost never should use `new[]` and `delete[]` and should just use a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: @elzell Often by allocating a few extra bytes and storing the length at the beginning of the allocated block. The returned pointer points to the byte immediately after where the length is stored. But of course this is implementation dependent

Comment: It isn't the variable (a, b) that matters, it's what they point to (arrays of 5 and 10 integers). As long as you delete all of your dynamically allocated memory once and once only you should be OK. std::vector (or std::unique_ptr) can make this a lot simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you can.  The reason being is that the information needed to accurately free up that memory is managed by the free store (the heap in most cases).  So it knows how to delete based on address rather than variable.  Often times this information is held in `*(ptr - x)` where x is the size of the tracking data.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it safe to delete [] them after swapping?

Yes.

> What if they have the same length?

The length is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can surely delete the pointer once your swapping is done. As you no longer need to point your array so in that case, it is safe to delete after swapping.

```
int *a;
int *b;
int *tmp;

a = new int[5];
b = new int[10];
tmp = a;
a = b;
b = tmp;

delete [] a;
delete [] b;
```

And this is the correct way of doing it. Great Job

Comment: *And this is the correct way of doing it. Great Job* `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` or `std::vector<T>` would be the correct way.  `new` and `delete` should not use used unless you absolutely have to (your writing you own library implementation)

Comment: @NathanOliver definitely that is a more appropriate way of doing it. Though for small code like swapping delete will do the job.

Comment: @NathanOliver Both are correct.  Yours is preferred.